# color transparent in IE8?

Tags: css, text, colors, internet-explorer-8, transparent

I got a bit of a headache from trying to get color:transparent to work in IE8.

Basically, I've got these buttons, which can be either anchors or input-elements:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Click me" />
<a class="button" href="SOME_URL">Click me</a>
```

When clicked, these buttons are given the class of `loading`, given them a spinner gif as a background image and setting `color:transparent` to make the text invisible, showing the spinner. This makes the buttons remain the same size when clicked while showing the spinner gif.

HOWEVER, IE8 does not support color:transparent and I'm having trouble coming up with another alternative.

Using `font-size:0`, `line-height:0`, `text-indent:-9999` or similar are no good in this case, since that would make it impossible to keep the size of the button.

I want to solve this with CSS if possible, so please don't waste your time posting a JavaScript solution.

Perhaps filters might be possible to setup for 'color', like done with gradients and 'opacity' below, but I've not yet find a way to do that.

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#000000', EndColorStr='#ffffff');
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50);
```

Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

IE8 doesn't understand the `rgba` property, so that's not a good answer. I would try using `visibility:hidden` IE8 understands that. That way, the text still takes up the same room, it's just hidden.

Comment: That would hide the entire button, not just the text.

Comment: @Henrik I realized that wouldn't work for your `input`. I'm wondering why `line-height` or `text-indent` won't work for you? Are you not specifying sizes of your buttons in CSS?

Comment: No, I'm not specifying sizes of my buttons since they can contain texts from a lot of different languages - hence can't be of fixed width.

Comment: OK, that makes sense why `line-height` etc. won't work for you. I'm not sure you can do a pure CSS solution. With the filters you have in your original question, you can add `00` to get the transparency. I'm just not sure you can target the button text.

`filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#00000000', EndColorStr='#00ffffff');`

Also, is there are reason you are avoiding JS? Just curious.

Comment: Well, I could use JavaScript to get the result I want - and I probably will (since this seems like a dead end). However, out of princible I try to do as little styling-related as possible with JavaScript - ideally just adding a new class to a parent element whenever the styling should change based on user interaction. I think this approach results in cleaner code that is easier to maintain.

Comment: If you only didn't have to appease IE8 :) I wrote a little JQuery script for you that will remove the `value` of the button. It will keep the original `height` and `width` so the button remains the same size, regardless of language. http://jsfiddle.net/9vEQT/2/

Good luck!!